# How to repeat onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, repeat

In the following code, why doesn't it change the color of the ball back to red if I click on it again?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
function farbe1(){
    var stern_style = document.getElementById('kugel1').style;
    var click;

   if(click != 0){
    stern_style.setProperty('fill','#F57200');
    click = 0;
    }
    else if(click == 0){
    stern_style.setProperty('fill','red');
    click = 1;
   }}

</script>

<svg height="2000" width="2000">

<circle id="kugel1" cx="1050" cy="500" r="50" style="fill:red;" onclick="farbe1()" />

</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

I am (as you can probably see) a beginner and would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because your flag get reset when you recall, move it out of function:

```
var click=0;
function farbe1(){

   var stern_style = document.getElementById('kugel1').style;    

   if(click != 0){
      stern_style.setProperty('fill','#F57200');
      click = 0;
    }
    else if(click == 0){
      stern_style.setProperty('fill','red');
      click = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `var click;` outside the function

```
var click;

function farbe1(){
var stern_style = document.getElementById('kugel1').style;

if(click != 0){
stern_style.setProperty('fill','#F57200');
click = 0;
}
else if(click == 0){
stern_style.setProperty('fill','red');
click = 1;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you declare `click` inside your `farbe1()` function. So it is set to undefined at every new call, and `click == 0` can never be reached.